# Is there a way to invoke a templated class on an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, generics, anonymous-types

Here's some code to give the idea.

```
public class C<T> { }
public class X {
  void M() {
    var V = new { W = 1 };
    var X = new C<V>(); // illegal
  }
}
```

So V is a variable of an anonymous type and I would like to instantiate class C with V as its argument. This requires a type argument, which I cannot supply.

This questions is similar but the answer is not much help in my case: [Why can't I instantiate a generic class inferring types from anonymous objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271661/why-cant-i-instantiate-a-generic-class-inferring-types-from-anonymous-objects)

The question behind the question is that I'm trying to do what IEnumerable can do.

---

Should have made it clear: I would really prefer not to do this by manipulating `object` or `Type` because you lose the benefits of strong typing and Intellisense.

---

For anyone interested, the project that needs this is described here: http://www.andl.org/2016/07/andl-net-making-progress/.

Comment: can you share the complete code of C<T>

Comment: This might help - [Create Generic Class instance based on Anonymous Type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280172/create-generic-class-instance-based-on-anonymous-type)

Comment: The answer to the question you linked to talks about using type inference via a helper method: `C<T> MakeC<T>(T arg) { return new C<T>(); }` - which enables the following: `var X = MakeC(V);`. How does that not answer your question?

Comment: @DevEstacion: not really, doesn't exist yet! This is experimental trying to produce something that works like `IEnumerable<T>` but isn't.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet: the accepted answer used a helper *class* (and there was a lot of chatter). Guess I missed that it was the helper *method* that is the critical bit.

Comment: @GiladGreen: thanks! It looks really obvious now, but it wasn't so obvious when I wrote the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use type inference if you have a factory method:

```
public class C<T>
{
    public C(T t)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public static class Factory
{
    public static C<T> Create<T>(T t)
    {
        return new C<T>(t);
    }
}

public class Thing
{
    void Foo()
    {
        var x = new { y = "z" };
        //var thing = new C(x); - doesn't work, you need to specify the generic parameter
        var thing = Factory.Create(x); // T is inferred here
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple. Yes, I can use that pattern multiple times to solve a range of related problems. Why didn't I think of that? See edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that since V is **instance** of anonymous type, not a type name itself.

You can create this type dynamically (assuming parameterless constructor in C<>):

```
var X = typeof (C<>)
            .MakeGenericType(V.GetType())
            .GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
            .Invoke(new object[0]);
```

Comment: Very nicde, +1 for that. Definitely something I will use, but not this time. See edit for why.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **type**, you can use pass **object** as a type.

Sample code:

```
public class C<T> 
{
    public T _t { get; set; }

    public C(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
    }

    public void TestMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_t.ToString());
    }
}

public class X
{
    public void M()
    {

        var V = new { W = 1 };

        var X = new C<object>(V); // everything is an object.

        X.TestMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I really want to keep the strong typing. See edit.

Comment: @david.pfx: I see your point, congrats on finding out the correct solution